# trigger voting button on nav link click

Tags: jquery

This is for the page https://miv-california-sbmr.squarespace.com/home

I’ve added a link in the nav (register to vote) with the external URL #vote

There is a button on the page that is a third party script that opens a register to vote form.

I am trying to trigger this button from the click of the nav link “register to vote”

I have tried the following code that is not working:

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">    
</script>


<script>
$(function() {  
$('a[href="#vote"]').click(function()  {     
$('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1530645326432_4684 a ').trigger('click');
return false;
});

 </script>
```

Does anyone know how I can modify this to trigger the rock the vote button on in the middle of the page?

Thanks

Comment: why not put the code that is in the register to vote function into its own function and reuse it in both cases? it seems to be working for the button on the link that you shared.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with how to do this. @JohnKane

Comment: you could do something like: function sharedLogic(){...} then add your onclick listeners to each case for example: $('a[href="#vote"]').click(sharedLogic);

Comment: And if you are on another page, like "Who we are", and that the user clicks on "Register to vote"...there isn't this button on the other pages...so a code that will click on the button (that doesn't exist) on the other pages won't work...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that an additional });  needed to be added.  The correct code is this:

```
<script>
$(function() {  
$('a[href="#vote"]').click(function()  {     
  $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1530645326432_4684 a ').trigger('click');
  return false;
});
}); 
</script>
```

@JohnKane